# How to get hint for JS functions in HTML-Tags?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, hint

I searched for many hours for a solution and found nothing. So, I hope you can help me.

I using the latest version of Visual Studio Code (1.61.0) for Linux: In Atom or WebStorm was it possible, to type in the script tags of a HTML file the first letters of a function or writing the name of an object with a dot and the IDE opens a tool tip to show the possible functions in other JS files. But this don't work in VS Code. Also it is not possible to go to a function source via CTRL + Click. If I go with my mouse over the in HTML written function call, the tool tip displays "any".

My installed extensions (which have maybe influence with the problem):

- HTML CSS Support
- JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly
- Visual Studio IntelliCode

Here are the files and a Screenshot of the "any" dialog. I hope someone knows a solution. Thank you!

index.html:

```
<script src="./js/hello.js">
    document.getElementById("display-div").innerHTML = helloWorld();
</script>
```

js/hello.js:

```
function getMessage() {
    return "Hi there...";
}
```

[image]

Comment: if you have a `src` attribute the tag content is ignored

Comment: Also I tried to set the script-src tag in the header and the function call in another <script> part in the body area. Same issue...

Comment: JS from other files only works for `import` statements, the JS engine does not analyze the HTML it is in